# Replace a value in dataframe in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe where this column has "Yes", "No", and blank (null). I tried to convert blank into a value, but it didn't work (this code used to work well on other scenarios). This "Agree" column is a factor variable. There is no error message in the console, but the blank is still blank.

```
Agree
Yes
No

No
Yes
Yes

No
No
Yes
```

`df$Agree[is.na(df$Agree)]   <- "No Response"`

Comment: Try `df$Agree[df$Agree=="",]   <- "No Response"` , or with space in `" "`

Answer (score 2):

Using **forcats** you could use the function `fct_recode()`.

```
> df <- tibble(Agree = factor(c('yes', 'no', ' ', 'no', 'yes', 'yes')))
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Agree
  <fct>
1 "yes"
2 "no" 
3 " "  
4 "no" 
5 "yes"
6 "yes"
> df %>% mutate(Agree = fct_recode(Agree, "No Response" = " "))
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Agree      
  <fct>      
1 yes        
2 no         
3 No Response
4 no         
5 yes        
6 yes
```

See other examples [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-levels).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added my example.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

your blank seems empty string column `''` instead of NA.  use

```
df$Agree[df$Agree == '']   <- "No Response"
```

See

```r
df
#>    Agree
#> 1    Yes
#> 2     No
#> 3       
#> 4     No
#> 5    Yes
#> 6    Yes
#> 7       
#> 8     No
#> 9     No
#> 10   Yes

df$Agree[df$Agree == '']   <- "No Response"

df
#>          Agree
#> 1          Yes
#> 2           No
#> 3  No Response
#> 4           No
#> 5          Yes
#> 6          Yes
#> 7  No Response
#> 8           No
#> 9           No
#> 10         Yes
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh, yes! The blank is an empty space, rather than a null value. Thanks!

Comment: Another question: why did I have to convert factor variable into character variable in order to replace the values? If the column "Agree" is a factor and I am trying to recode "Yes" into "1", it gives me this error msg in the console: Warning message: In [<-.factor(*tmp*, df$Agree == "Yes", value = c(NA, 2L, NA, : invalid factor level, NA generated – . Once I turn "Agree" into a character variable, the replace code works out.

Comment: When you work with factors, you can not change a value into something that is not already defined as a factor level. Factors are difficult to work with, and I frequently change all my factors to characters during data processing, than back to factors if necessary for the analysis

Comment: Got it. Thanks!